# How to combine proportions across regions statistics

Tags: percentages

How do I combine county 1 (C1), county 2 (C2)and county 3 (c3) to get the overall race/ethnicity proportions for the region?

- C1 is 47.6% white, 45.9% Black or African American, 3.5% Asian, 2.5% multiracial, and 4.1% Hispanic or Latino.
- C2 is 68.2%white, 24.9% African American or Black, 4.5% Asian, 2.2% multiracial, and 3% Hispanic or Latino.
- C3 is 89.9% white, 5.1% Black or African American, 2.7% Asian, 2% multiracial, and 3.4% Hispanic or Latino .

The overall population of C1 is 302,838. The overall population of C2 is 996,945 the overall population of C3 is 399,182.

So, eyeballing it, there is disproportionate victimization by race/ethnicity, in this region, see below. But I need the math part. E.g., in these 3 counties combined,  xx are white, xx black, xx Asian, etc.

The region with 3 counties combined reported 26.3% (n=15) of survivors were white/Caucasian, 59.6% (n=34) were Black/African American, 3.5% (n=2) were Hispanic/Latinx, 1 was Asian American, 1 was another race, and 7% (n=4) were Multiracial.

Comment: The data suffices to compute the exact number (well, rounded number)  of people of each type in each country.  Work from there.

Comment: So, I can convert % to n, combine n s for each category, and convert back to % of the overall population (3 counties population combined)?

Comment: Sure.  If you can back out to the original numbers, you can do whatever computation you want.